# Ошибка при попытке отправить сообщение на сервер по защищенному соединению

Tags: ssl, tls, tcpclient

Ситуация следующая, я создаю сервер используя протокол Tls1.2, на основании созданных и самоподписаных сертификатов. Происходит подключение. При успешном подключении срабатывает callback и я хочу передать запрос на сервер используя метод Write(byte[])

```
private static void SecureConnectionResultsCallback(object sender, SecureConnectionResults args)
    {
        if (args.AsyncException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.AsyncException.ToString());
            return;
        }

        SslStream stream = args.SecureStream;

        Console.WriteLine($"Получено защищенное соединение");

        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[5120];
            int bytes;
            var command = "GetControlUnitReportsList";
            byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);                
            stream.Write(request);
            var ppp = ReadStream(stream);
            stream.Flush();
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Поток завершен");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
            _client?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Возникает ошибка в моменте `stream.Write(request);`

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Эта операция допустима только при использовании контекста, подлинность которого успешно подтверждена.'

Но у меня же и так защищенное соединение. Подскажите как передать сообщение, не используя Write или может быть я смотрю на проблему не с той стороны.